# How does Tor browser find hidden websites

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, onion-services, onion-routing, browsers, onioncat

I was reading about search engines and i have seen that google for example is crawling and expending it's indexes by finding new links inside of the current websites he is scanning at the time.
So my question is, how does Tor do that? 
How can you find websites that doesn't have any links pointing to it?
How does Tor locates websites that are made especially to be hidden?

If you have any sources or even better a simple detailed answer for me it would be truly great

Thank You

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about web crawling, and not specific to Tor.

Answer (score 1):

> So my question is, how does Tor do that?

It doesn't.

> How can you find websites that doesn't have any links pointing to it?

At best, either brute-force guessing or some information leak outside of links from another web page.

Depending on how much unguessable information is in the link, this could be infeasible.